# Methods for fitting a distribution to regression data

Tags: regression, distributions, multiple-regression, survival

I'm hoping to find a method/algorithm/approach for fitting to a distribution to regression data.

Essentially I have a problem where I have survival data with independent variables, but only cases that actually had an event. All data where an event did not occur before censoring has been purged.

I understand a cox model should still work here, but as there is no censored data it would not be as strong or appropriate as typical survival data. I assume there are other methods that would work better.

Really I have a regression problem, attempting to use multiple independent variables to predict time-to-event, but I need a distribution/curve output instead of a single point. Then I can produce different probabilities of an event occurring within one week, two weeks etc, for new cases.

What are some approaches or methods for doing so?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a reason why the standard survival analysis methods wouldn't work here, you can choose to go non-parametric (e.g. Kaplan-Meier), semi-parametric (Cox proportional hazards) or fully parametric (accelerated failure time models). All of these can provide you with estimates of the survival function over time, obviously with different assumptions underpinning them.

The larger problem is that you do not have all relevant data; the power of these methods is exactly in their ability to incorporate censored observations into the survival estimate to the extent they are still informative. They work just as well when everything has been observed. You won't have much of an issue if you have follow-up until a large majority of the sample experienced the event, but in practice this is not often the case.

If your uncensored-only sample is not sufficiently representative of the full survival curve your best option is to go get the censored observations. Otherwise you'll have to make strong, possibly unverifiable assumptions on the censoring distribution, or accept that your estimates will likely be flawed. No model can fix a lack of reliable data.

Comment: The standard survival methods should certainly still work but I assume that due to the lack of censored data, would lose a lot of strength compared to other methods. Without this data I'm ending up with a regression problem, which is fine for my needs.

I assume there are methods, similar to the cox, but fit distributions to more typical regression data and would be more suitable for me. I'm hoping to find something like that.

Comment: No, these methods don't *give away* power to handle censoring, it is rather the opposite. Your first choice is whether you want to make parametric assumptions on the time-to-event, if so an AFT model is going to be as powerful as any (provided your assumptions are correct). It is rather that non-survival methods *cannot* handle censoring, so they are always at most as powerful as what your are being forced to do now if you cannot re-include censoring in some way.

Comment: The problem is that such "complete-data analysis produces unbiased estimates only if the missing (censored observations) are missing (censored) completely at random" ([Leung et al, Annu. Rev. Public Health 1997. 18:83–104](https://doi.org/10.1146/annurev.publhealth.18.1.83), page 90). That's an extremely strong assumption.